# ISPConfig iPhone blank screen

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, iphone

If I go to https://example.com:8080 from iPhone (Safari or Google Chrome) I get blank screen.

If I go to the same page from laptop with Windows and Chrome, I get the correct page.

Access logs:

```
X.X.X.X - - [28/Apr/2016:10:27:46 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2454 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12"
X.X.X.X - - [28/Apr/2016:10:27:54 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 447 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12"
```

There are no errors in error logs, I also have SOAP extension installed.

Comment: are your devices on the same network?

Comment: no,  server is in the other country.

Comment: Then, easy answer, your ISP is blocking your conections.

Comment: Try to see the pacge source: http://www.howtogeek.com/204991/how-to-view-web-page-source-code-on-your-iphone-or-ipad/